# SQL local copy/backup

Tags: sql, duplicates, backup

I build home IoT network. I plan to have raspberry on local network and all sensors/nodes to communicate with raspberry. All sensors/nodes data should be stored locally in SQL database. As storage is limited I wish to keep just few days on local SQL database. When WEB is available I wish to update another (same table format) SQL database on WEB SQL server. The other thing is app to see the data and to send commands. When app is started up it 1'st check if it can reach LAN SQL database, and if that is not available (I'm out of home) then try to connect WEB SQL database. And app can receive data from database and can send commands to database.

if WEB is down (rare event) I can access last few days from local network when I'm at home.

So is there already some functions built into SQL to achieve that functionality?

1. Have local SQL just of last few days with sync in larger database on the WEB.
2. To propagate NEW data from LAN to WEB database
3. To propagate NEW data from WEB to LAN database

Maybe stupid question but I'm barely know how to work with SQL.

Thanks

Comment: What's the SQL engine used? (Oracle, MySQL, postGREs etc)

Comment: I prefer MySQL.